# HTML Place text next to another text?

Tags: html, image, text

This is kind of hard to explain but I'm trying to place a text next to another text. A picture is worth a thousand words so here's what I'm trying to achieve.

**Here's a picture of what it should look like**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LueqE.jpg
http://i39.tinypic.com/24kxft3.jpg

And this what I have so far. As you can see, the text that I want to place next to this text is not where it should be. I'm talking about the bold text that should be on right "9.1, Date, Author".

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/NmUaX/20/

**HTML**

```
    <li class="post" >
        <article class="in-column" style="height:300px;"> <a href="http://yahoo.com"> <p class="article-title" style="font-size:26px; padding-bottom:10px;">Grumpy Cat</p><img src="http://cdn.dashburst.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Grumpy-Cat.jpg" border="0" height="200" width="300" style="float:left; padding-right:20px;"></a>
            <p class="excerpt" style="width:700px; line-height:20px;">Grumpy Cat, real name Tardar Sauce, is a female cat and Internet celebrity known for her grumpy facial expression. Her owner Tabatha Bundesen says that her permanently grumpy-looking face is due to feline dwarfism. Grumpy Cat, real name Tardar Sauce, is a female cat and Internet celebrity known for her grumpy facial expression. Her owner Tabatha Bundesen says that her permanently grumpy-looking face is due to feline dwarfism.</p> 

            <p class="excerpt" style="float:right; font-size:70px; font-family:Segoe UI;"><b>9.1</b></p>
        <p class="excerpt" style="float:right; font-size:14px; font-family:Segoe UI;"><b>Date: </b>2 June 2012<br/><b>Author: </b> John Smith</p>

            </article>
      </li>

      </section>
      </section>
```

**CSS**

```
 article.in-column {    
      border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding-left: 25px;
      padding-right: 25px;   
      padding-top: 15px; 

  }

  article.in-column .excerpt {
      color: #2f2f2f;
      font-size: 11px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;   

  }

  p.article-title{
          line-height: 19px;
          margin: 5px 0px;
          color: #151515;
          font-weight:bold;
          font-size:16px;
      }
```

Comment: If you want the stuff that you float right on top, then you have to place it before the article content. Of course there’s other ways how you could get it up there – since the text content is very limited and predictable in size, absolute positioning would maybe be an option too. Or making the picture container, article text and info all inline-block and have them vertically align to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that content `<p>` Element you need to give `width:500px; float:left`

and the bold text 9.1 you need to give a `line-height:50px`

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NmUaX/21/

Answer (score 1):

I tried replacing your HTML (and some CSS) on the right-floating  element:

```
<div style="float:right;">
    <div class="excerpt" style=" font-size:70px; font-family:Segoe UI;">
        <b>9.1</b>
    </div>
    <div class="excerpt" style="font-size:14px; font-family:Segoe UI;">
        <b>Date: </b>2 June 2012
        <br/><b>Author: </b> John Smith
    </div>
</div>
```

if you want to float an element to the right top, it would be best to place it before the article content. Also, it would be best to wrap both elements (the 9.1 and the date) into one container before floating them to the right.